# render_template from Flask blueprint uses other blueprint's template

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app with blueprints.  Each blueprint provides some templates.  When I try to render the `index.html` template from the second blueprint, the first blueprint's template is rendered instead.  Why is blueprint2 overriding blueprint1's templates?  How can I render each blueprint's templates?

```
app/
    __init__.py
    blueprint1/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        templates/
            index.html
    blueprint2/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        templates/
            index.html
```

`blueprint2/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp1 = Blueprint('bp1', __name__, template_folder='templates', url_prefix='/bp1')

from . import views
```

`blueprint2/views.py`:

```
from flask import render_template
from . import bp1

@bp1.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

`app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from blueprint1 import bp1
from blueprint2 import bp2

application = Flask(__name__)
application.register_blueprint(bp1)
application.register_blueprint(bp2)
```

If I change the order the blueprints are registered, then blueprint2's templates override blueprint1's.

```
application.register_blueprint(bp2)
application.register_blueprint(bp1)
```

Comment: You should post your `__init__.py` files.

Comment: Thanks, now posted.

Comment: I guess the problem is in `Blueprint('bp1', ...` you should register the full name of the directory as in `Blueprint('blueprint1',`

Comment: That is not the case, I changed the name but nothing new happened. I find that the order I registered the blueprint determined which page to display. The first one I registered will override the second template.

Comment: Have you tried to change `template_folder='templates'`? maybe to `template_folder='blueprint2/templates'`? or giving it a full path?

Comment: One way or another, one of the index.html will override the other one... When it is relative path like blueprint2/templates, the blueprint2 will override blueprint1, and when it is absolute path the blueprint1 will override blueprint2.

Comment: Remember....you are defining the `Blueprint` with a `url_prefix=bp1`...so I guess the url will be something like ... `localhost:5000/bp1/` or `localhost:5000/bp1/index`

Answer (score 17):

This is working exactly as intended, although not as you expect.

Defining a template folder for a blueprint only adds the folder to the template search path.  It does *not* mean that a call to `render_template` from a blueprint's view will only check that folder.

Templates are looked up first at the application level, then in the order blueprints were registered.  This is so that an extension can provide templates that can be overridden by an application.

The solution is to use separate folders *within* the template folder for templates related to specific blueprints.  It's still possible to override them, but much harder to do so accidentally.

```
app/
    blueprint1/
        templates/
            blueprint1/
                index.html
    blueprint2/
        templates/
            blueprint2/
                index.html
```

Point each blueprint at its `templates` folder.

```py
bp = Blueprint('bp1', __name__, template_folder='templates')
```

When rendering, point at the specific template under the `templates` folder.

```py
render_template('blueprint1/index.html')
```

See [Flask issue #1361](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1361) for more discussion.

Answer (score -1):

I vaguely remember having trouble with something like this early on.  You haven't posted all of your code, but I have four suggestions based on what you've written.  Try the first, test it, and then if it still is not working, try the next ones, but independently test them to see if they work:

First, I cant't see your `views.py` file, so be sure you're importing the appropriate blueprint in your `views.py` files:

```
from . import bp1   # in blueprint1/views.py
from . import bp2   # in blueprint2/views.py
```

Second, you may need to fix the relative import statements in `__init__.py` as follows (note the period preceding the subfolders):

```
from .blueprint1 import blueprint1 as bp1
from .blueprint2 import blueprint2 as bp2
```

Third, since you're hardcoding the path to your templates in your `render_template` function, try removing `template_folder='templates'` from your blueprint definition.

Fourth, it looks like you named the url_prefix for your blueprint as "/bp1" when you registered it.  Therefore, if the hard coded link to your file system still does not work:

```
render_template('blueprint1/index.html')
```

then also try this and see what happens:

```
render_template('bp1/index.html')
```

Again, I can't see your full code, but I hope this helps.